# Как скомпилировать программу с интерфейсом на PySide2 в .exe файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, pyside2

Есть **`2`** файла: **`main.py`** и **`window.py`**. Сам интерфейс и функции в `window.py`.

Интерфейс писал в *Qt Designer*. 
Программа типа лоадера со строкой под данные, кнопкой "входа" (пока что исполняется просто переход по ссылке в случае введения верных данных) и закрытия программы.

Просто `pyinstaller`'ом не получается. После компиляции и попытки запуска **.exe**'шника либо открывается *консоль*, либо ничего не открывается, либо выдает ошибку "**`failed to execute script main`**" - различия между тем, что произойдет кроются в флагах, которые я ставлю при компиляции.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from window import Ui_Form

class Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Form, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 305)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Form()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**window.py**

```
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import webbrowser
 
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(400, 305)
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(
            u"C:/Users/\u041f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c/Desktop/anonymous-512.png",
            QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        Form.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.label = QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(130, 60, 51, 21))
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(u"lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QRect(130, 80, 131, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("NewUser")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QRect(130, 130, 131, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText("••••••••••")
        self.lineEdit_2.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.checkBox = QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName(u"checkBox")
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QRect(130, 150, 91, 31))
        self.label_2 = QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QRect(130, 110, 51, 21))
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(130, 180, 129, 23))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.bp)
        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QRect(130, 210, 129, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(exit)
 
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
 
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
 
    def bp(self):
        if self.lineEdit.text() == "andrey" and self.lineEdit_2.text() == "1":
            webbrowser.open('https://imgur.com/a/hMeWiqp', new=2)
        elif self.lineEdit.text() == "sergey" and self.lineEdit_2.text() == "1":
            webbrowser.open('https://imgur.com/a/nlmZiUo', new=2)
        else:
            self.lineEdit.clear()
            self.lineEdit_2.clear()
            self.lineEdit.setFocus()
 
 
    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Loader", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Username", None))
        self.checkBox.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Remember me", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Password", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Log in", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Exit", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

---

**Из командной строки во время компиляции**

```
D:\PycharmProjects\main>pyinstaller -w -F main.py
84 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
84 INFO: Python: 3.8.1
85 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
85 INFO: wrote D:\PycharmProjects\main\main.spec
87 INFO: UPX is not available.
89 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\PycharmProjects\\main', 'D:\\PycharmProjects\\main']
89 INFO: checking Analysis
89 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
90 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
92 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
101 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3309 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
3310 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'd:\\python38\\lib'
5464 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
5597 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
5599 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by d:\python38\python.exe
5690 INFO: Analyzing D:\PycharmProjects\main\main.py
5712 INFO: Processing module hooks...
5712 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
5714 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
5809 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
5816 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
5817 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PySide2.py"...
6088 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PySide2.QtNetwork.py"...
6392 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PySide2.QtWidgets.py"...
6603 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
6604 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
6606 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
6659 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
6805 INFO: checking Tree
6806 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
6807 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
6901 INFO: checking Tree
6902 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
6902 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
6916 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PySide2.QtCore.py"...
7007 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PySide2.QtGui.py"...
7184 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
7219 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
7222 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
7225 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
7228 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pyside2.py'
7235 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
8105 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of d:\python38\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtWidgets.pyd
8125 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of d:\python38\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtCore.pyd
8147 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of d:\python38\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtGui.pyd
8168 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of d:\python38\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtNetwork.pyd
8857 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of d:\python38\lib\site-packages\PySide2\pyside2.abi3.dll
8998 INFO: Looking for eggs
8998 INFO: Using Python library d:\python38\python38.dll
8999 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
9003 INFO: Warnings written to D:\PycharmProjects\main\build\main\warn-main.txt
9061 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to D:\PycharmProjects\main\build\main\xref-main.html
9092 INFO: checking PYZ
9093 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
9094 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\PycharmProjects\main\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz
9774 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\PycharmProjects\main\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
9786 INFO: checking PKG
9786 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
9787 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
19476 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
19498 INFO: Bootloader d:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\runw.exe
19498 INFO: checking EXE
19499 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
19499 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
19500 INFO: Appending archive to EXE D:\PycharmProjects\main\dist\main.exe
19545 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: 1. опубликуйте модуль `window.py`.  2. Напишите как вы запускаете `pyinstaller` с какими флагами.

Comment: для сокрытия консоли - флаг `-w`, для компиляции единым файлом - флаг `-F`

Comment: @S.Nick 1. https://pastebin.com/dPniaZ9u 2. пробовал запускать с -w и -F. как по отдельности, так и одновременно

Comment: Попробуйте завернуть `main` в try-except. В блоке `except` можно будет вывести информацию по исключению.

Comment: @Bogdan скажу честно, не имею понятия, что это и зачем. попробовал найти в интернете, но, к сожалению, ничего не понял. думаю, что мне нужно изучить это. сейчас такими навыками не владею :)

Comment: Подскажите, может не понимаю чего. Запускаю просто "pyinstaller main.py" (допустим без флагов). С window.py ничего же делать не надо? Первый раз компилирую. Если все верно, то тогда вопрос все еще открыт. UPD. добавил текст из командной строки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По первой ссылке в google `pyinstaller webbrowser` 
получил https://medium.com/@mahmudahsan/how-to-make-python-executable-in-windows-pyinstaller-webbrowser-f7ad8e988dea

```
pyinstaller -F -w questions_1075846.py
```

Правда заменил

```
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(exit)                      # ???
```

на

```
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)       # +++
```

потому как я такого выхода не встречал !

**questions_1075846.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import webbrowser

#from window import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(400, 305)
        icon = QIcon('Ok.png')
#        icon.addFile(
#            u"C:/Users/\u041f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c/Desktop/anonymous-512.png",
#            QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        Form.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.label = QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(130, 60, 51, 21))
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(u"lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QRect(130, 80, 131, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("NewUser")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QRect(130, 130, 131, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText("••••••••••")
        self.lineEdit_2.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.checkBox = QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName(u"checkBox")
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QRect(130, 150, 91, 31))
        self.label_2 = QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QRect(130, 110, 51, 21))
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(130, 180, 129, 23))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.bp)
        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QRect(130, 210, 129, 23))

#        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(exit)                      # ???  <<-----<
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)        # +++

        self.retranslateUi(Form)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def bp(self):
        if self.lineEdit.text() == "andrey" and self.lineEdit_2.text() == "1":
            webbrowser.open('https://imgur.com/a/hMeWiqp', new=2)
        elif self.lineEdit.text() == "sergey" and self.lineEdit_2.text() == "1":
            webbrowser.open('https://imgur.com/a/nlmZiUo', new=2)
        else:
            self.lineEdit.clear()
            self.lineEdit_2.clear()
            self.lineEdit.setFocus()


    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Loader", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Username", None))
        self.checkBox.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Remember me", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Password", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Log in", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Exit", None))
    # retranslateUi


class Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Form, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 305)

        print("Openning Favorite Sites")

        with open("sites.txt") as fobj:
            try:
                for num, url in enumerate(fobj):
                    #webbrowser.open_new_tab(url.strip())
                    pass
            except Exception as e:
                print('Error: {}'.format(e))

        print("\nEnjoy!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Form()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**sites.txt**

```
https://imgur.com/a/hMeWiqp
https://imgur.com/a/nlmZiUo
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWidgets: %1 не является приложением Win32.

Process finished with exit code 1
Это выдает в pycharm. Через python main.py все нормально. Но после компиляции и запуска все та же ошибка. Проблема где-то у меня) Явно уже не в коде

Comment: @AtommX я не понял, что у вас установлен `PySide2` или `PyQt5`?  Если `PySide2`, то поменяйте в импорте `PyQt5` на `PySide2`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вам нужно установить модуль `win32com`.
2. Скопируйте файл `shiboken2.abi3.dll` из `Lib\site-packages\shiboken2` в
   `Lib\site-packages\PySide2`
3. замените `self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(exit)` в `window.py` на `self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(sys.exit)`
4. Импортируйте модуль `sys` в `window.py`: import sys
5. Используйте эту команду в cmd:
   `pyinstaller -F main.py -w -p "C:\Program
   Files\QtDesigner\Qt5Core.dll"`. Путь к файлу Qt5Core.dll замените на
   ваш.

Comment: "failed to execute script main" после открытия exe-файла

Comment: Дополнил ответ.