# python .py to exe

Tags: pyinstaller

Извините если уже такое было, но ответ найти не смог.
Установлено:
Операционная система: openSUSE Tumbleweed 20210810
Версия KDE Plasma: 5.22.4
Версия KDE Frameworks: 5.84.0
Версия Qt: 5.15.2
Версия ядра: 5.13.8-1-default (64-бита)
Графическая платформа: X11
Процессоры: 2 × AMD A4-6300 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
Память: 7,2 ГиБ ОЗУ
Графический процессор: AMD ARUBA

```
vadiki@localhost:~> pyinstaller --version
5.0.dev0
vadiki@localhost:~> python --version
Python 2.7.18
vadiki@localhost:~> python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
```

устанавливал

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

так-же пробовал

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz
```

Вот еще если поможет

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5-tools in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (5.15.4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5-plugins<5.15.4.3,>=5.15.4.2.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyqt5-tools) (5.15.4.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyqt5-tools) (0.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5==5.15.4 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyqt5-tools) (5.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: click in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyqt5-tools) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyqt5==5.15.4->pyqt5-tools) (12.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyqt5==5.15.4->pyqt5-tools) (5.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: qt5-tools<5.15.2.2,>=5.15.2.1.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyqt5-plugins<5.15.4.3,>=5.15.4.2.2->pyqt5-tools) (5.15.2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: qt5-applications<5.15.2.3,>=5.15.2.2.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from qt5-tools<5.15.2.2,>=5.15.2.1.2->pyqt5-plugins<5.15.4.3,>=5.15.4.2.2->pyqt5-tools) (5.15.2.2.2)
```

/home/vadiki/.local/bin/ добавлен в PATH

В общем дело вот в чем.

```
vadiki@localhost:~> pyinstaller /home/vadiki/py1/Python.py                         
319 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.0.dev0
319 INFO: Python: 3.8.10
321 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.13.8-1-default-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5
322 INFO: wrote /home/vadiki/Python.spec
326 INFO: UPX is not available.
327 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/vadiki/py1', '/home/vadiki']
776 INFO: checking Analysis
784 INFO: Building because inputs changed
785 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
787 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
808 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6382 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_find_module_path/hook-distutils.py'.
6383 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/usr/lib64/python3.8'
10354 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
10705 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/lib64/libpython3.8.so.1.0'
10736 INFO: Analyzing /home/vadiki/py1/Python.py
10810 INFO: Processing module hooks...
10811 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
10813 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 124, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 775, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 707, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/home/vadiki/Python.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['/home/vadiki/py1/Python.py'],
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 269, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 437, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/analysis.py", line 326, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/imphook.py", line 398, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/imphook.py", line 361, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/compat.py", line 576, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 522, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1027, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 852, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.utils.hooks.qt import add_qt5_dependencies
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/hooks/qt.py", line 143, in <module>
    pyqt6_library_info = QtLibraryInfo('PyQt6')
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/hooks/qt.py", line 59, in __init__
    if hooks.is_module_satisfies("PyQt6 >= 6.0.3"):
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/hooks/__init__.py", line 474, in is_module_satisfies
    version = get_module_attribute(module_name, version_attr)
  File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/hooks/__init__.py", line 337, in get_module_attribute
    raise AttributeError('Module %r has no attribute %r' % (module_name, attr_name))
AttributeError: Module 'PyQt6' has no attribute '__version__'
```

И причем тут PyQt6? Он не установлен. Пробовал и его устанавливать.
3-и сутки мучаюсь. у всех все везде получается - у меня - нет! Помогите пожалуйста и объясните доступно. В каком месте я дебил?

Вот что после установки PyQt6.

```
pyinstaller /home/vadiki/py1/Python.py 
296 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.0.dev0
296 INFO: Python: 3.8.10
297 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.13.8-1-default-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5
298 INFO: wrote /home/vadiki/Python.spec
302 INFO: UPX is not available.
304 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/vadiki/py1', '/home/vadiki']
732 INFO: checking Analysis
739 INFO: Building because inputs changed
740 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
742 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
760 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6258 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_find_module_path/hook-distutils.py'.
6259 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/usr/lib64/python3.8'
10108 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
10435 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/lib64/libpython3.8.so.1.0'
10466 INFO: Analyzing /home/vadiki/py1/Python.py
10541 INFO: Processing module hooks...
10543 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
10546 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so'
10972 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
10992 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
10995 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so'
11054 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
11057 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
11153 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.abi3.so'
11253 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
11254 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
11257 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
11291 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
11291 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
11903 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
11912 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
11918 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
11923 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
11928 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_inspect.py'
11931 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
11948 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/math.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/select.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_datetime.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/unicodedata.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_random.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_asyncio.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_contextvars.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_queue.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/mmap.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_posixshmem.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/array.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_multiprocessing.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/termios.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sha3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_blake2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sha256.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_md5.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sha1.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sha512.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_csv.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/binascii.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/resource.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_multibytecodec.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_codecs_jp.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_codecs_kr.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_codecs_iso2022.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_codecs_cn.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_codecs_tw.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/_codecs_hk.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.abi3.so'
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so'
13946 WARNING: Cannot find libicudata.so.56 (needed by /home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libicuuc.so.56)
ldd: предупреждение: у вас нет прав на выполнение `/lib64/libcap.so.2'
14140 WARNING: Cannot find libicuuc.so.56 (needed by /home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libicui18n.so.56)
14141 WARNING: Cannot find libicudata.so.56 (needed by /home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libicui18n.so.56)
15609 INFO: Looking for eggs
15610 INFO: Using Python library /lib64/libpython3.8.so.1.0
15617 INFO: Warnings written to /home/vadiki/build/Python/warn-Python.txt
15683 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /home/vadiki/build/Python/xref-Python.html
15708 INFO: checking PYZ
15713 INFO: Building because toc changed
15713 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/vadiki/build/Python/PYZ-00.pyz
16540 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/vadiki/build/Python/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
16547 INFO: checking PKG
16548 INFO: Building because toc changed
16548 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
16655 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
16658 INFO: Bootloader /home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-64bit-intel/run
16658 INFO: checking EXE
16659 INFO: Building because toc changed
16659 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
16718 INFO: Appending archive to ELF section in EXE /home/vadiki/build/Python/Python
16901 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
16904 INFO: checking COLLECT
WARNING: The output directory "/home/vadiki/dist/Python" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/N)y
On your own risk, you can use the option `--noconfirm` to get rid of this question.
27423 INFO: Removing dir /home/vadiki/dist/Python
27466 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
32590 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

вот как устанавливал

```
pip3 install pyqt6
pip3 install pyqt6-tools
```

Код самой программы

```
    import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QLineEdit


def dialog():
    mbox = QMessageBox()

    mbox.setText("Your allegiance has been noted")
    mbox.setDetailedText(
        "You are now a disciple and subject of the all-knowing Guru")
    mbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)

    mbox.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Guru99')

    label = QLabel(w)
    label.setText("Behold the Guru, Guru99")
    label.move(100, 130)
    label.show()

    line = QLineEdit()
    line.move(100, 130)
    line.show()

    btn = QPushButton(w)
    btn.setText('Beheld')
    btn.move(110, 150)
    btn.show()
    btn.clicked.connect(dialog)

    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128728/discussion-on-question-by---python-py-to-exe).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как скомпилировать программу с интерфейсом на Qt в exe файл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1075846/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-qt-%d0%b2-exe-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться библиотекой  `auto-py-to-exe`. Он тоже конвертирует py-файлы в exe. У него очень удобный графический интерфейс. Чтобы решить вашу ошибку, вам нужно в окне запущенной библиотеки нажать "дополнительно", затем "скрытый импорт", и добавить библиотеки, которые вы импортируете в свой .py-файл, то есть вам нужно Pyqt6.

Установка: `pip install auto-py-to-exe`

Подробнее можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe)